# Regex from rules stored in a database for ASTERISK using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, asterisk

I'm trying to create a kind of REGEX with dynamic variables 
with PHP using some pre-defined values stored in a Database table, in order to 
validate a Dial String from Asterisk.
The database has 
a table for outgoing rules, which each user may create to be applied to his/her extension.

Variables in PHP can be like this:

```
$N = '[23456789]';
$Z = '\d*'; //(any digit, any occurrence)
$X = '[0-9]';
$x = '[0-9]';
```

numbers in the rule will be considered as number itself

symbols in the rule will be considered as symbol itself (only * and # will be accepted in the database as symbols)

The table is something like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| id | extension | order | description | ruledigits | ruletype | subtract  | prefix | suffix |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1005 |     1 |             | 9XX        | Block    | null      | null   | null   |
|  2 |      1005 |     2 |             | 302NXXXXXX | Mod      | null      | 1      | null   |
|  3 |      2005 |     1 |             | 00Z        | Mod      | 2         | 011    | null   |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

So, if 1005 Extension DIALS 908 (no more digits), that call should be blocked 
according to the Action field. if 1005 Extension Dials 3025555555 (no more 
digits), that Call will be prefixed with number 1.

Iif 1005 Extension Dials 00325698289115 (international), that Call will NOT 
me modified according to Rule # 3, since that rule ONLY applies to EXT 2005, so 
the CALL will be sent as it was Dialed to the Server.

If that same last Call was made by 2005, the number would MATCH the rule, 
since it begins with 00 and Z is ANY DIGIT ANY OCURRENCE. So, the dialed number will be Subtracted "2" digits from the beginning, and then prefixed with "011" before being sent to the trunk.

The important field here I think is ruledigits (and of course extension), 
which will be used by PHP for the ARRAY of rules per EXT. then the action will 
be read only if the condition was meet.

And the condition something like this, although this one only represents just 
1 rule and case:

```
if(preg_match("/^1$N$X$N(555)$Z/", $number))
{
    // $number format matches
    echo "yes"; // apply the action according the table
}
else
{
    echo "no"; // no action applied, proceed with the call.
}
```

I would need condition(s) that must be created on the fly as soon as the actual 
Call (requesting the access to the database through a php script) finds that 
there are not just 1, but some rules created for THAT extension individually.

How can I make or design a General function that can Access the database "rules" 
table, and ARRAY the group of all the conditions created under the caller 
extension in order to apply them to the actual call?

Note: The field 
"ruledigits" on the table "rules" will only accept the following characters:

N, Z, *, #, or Any number.

Comment: Okay, first things first, this needs to be simplified. Waaay too much background information, thanks for trying to make sure we understand what's going on, but it's going to scare people away.

Comment: I've read through it and it seems to basically be, how can I build a regex from rules stored in a database - if so, give us example db/table structure and content (small amount), plus some test cases etc. Short and sweet, to the point.

Comment: Okay as per update, you would want to parse `302NXXXXXX` to end up with `302$N$X$X$X$X$X$X` (i.e. `302[23456789][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` or simplified: `302[2-9]\d{6}`) ? And similar for `00Z` and `9XX` (or whatever). Then if that pattern matches, use `ruletype` to determine what happens

Comment: you got it. Exactly. every call (dial string) made by an extension will be checked against any existing rule for that Extension in the database table.  If not rule, or if it didn't match the condition, then the call may proceed without any change applied.  Notice that "ruledigits" field can accept only these characters: N, X, Z, *, #, or Any number. i.e.: NX52XXXXXX

Comment: What would `*` or `#` mean? Or are they literal characters?

Comment: By the way, I've made quite a big edit to your question. I'm pretty sure it's an improvement, but you may want to double check it

Comment: Wow, thanks for those repsonses. My first time here in stackoverflow. I will review the answers to see what happens in Live.  And yes, * and # are Literally characters. For example, I have some local Extensions in this format:  0009*1505 (I separate first set of numbers as MAIN USER ID number, then the other Set the SHORT Number EXTENSION) So, if a Rule needs to be applied to it, would be:  XXXX*XXXX

Comment: How did you get on with this in the end?

Comment: (Kind of late responding here). I was stuck with other project, and didnt have the chance to test this. But, Yes, your solution made it.   I will play with the different options, Mods and scenarios to make it work in a productive server.  Thanks for the time, detailed explanation, code, and sample test, buddy. Very well written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would personally approach using MySQL data to build Regex patterns for checking data:

```
//Simplified array
$dbResults = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'extension' => 1005,
        'order' => 1,
        'description' => 'rule 1',
        'ruledigits' => '9XX',
        'prefix' => null,
        'ruletype' => 'Block'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'extension' => 1005,
        'order' => 2,
        'description' => 'rule 2',
        'ruledigits' => '302NXXXXXX',
        'prefix' => 1,
        'ruletype' => 'Mod'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'extension' => 2005,
        'order' => 3,
        'description' => 'rule 3',
        'ruledigits' => '00Z',
        'prefix' => '001',
        'ruletype' => 'Mod'
    )
);
$regexParts = array(
    'N' => '[2-9]'
    ,'Z' => '\d*'
    ,'X' => '\d'
    ,'x' => '\d'
);
//Static test vars
$userExt = 1005;
$dialTests = array('00325698289115','908','3025555555');
echo 'Testing user extension: '.$userExt;
echo '<br /><br />';
//This loop is for testing purposes only, the contents are all the live system would use
foreach($dialTests as $testNo)
{
    $actionTaken = 'None';
    //By default, if nothing happens, make sure the final number is the original one we saw
    $finalNo = $testNo;
    foreach($dbResults as $row)
    {
        if($userExt != $row['extension']) continue;//If it's not the right extension, skip the rest of this loop iteration's code and move on to the next row
        $regex = '';
        $tokens = str_split($row['ruledigits']);//Turn the string into an array, so we can parse each character individually
        foreach($tokens as $token)
        {
            if(isset($regexParts[$token])) $regex .= $regexParts[$token];//If the letter has a special meaning, use that
            else $regex .= $token;//else just throw that exact letter/number in
        }
        if(preg_match('#^'.$regex.'$#',$testNo)>0)
        {
            $actionTaken = $row['ruletype'];//Log what action has been taken
            if($actionTaken=='Mod')
            {
                $finalNo = $row['prefix'].$testNo;//Do the mod action
            }
            else if($actionTaken=='Block')
            {
                $finalNo = false;//Nullify the final number, so we know to block the call later on
            }
        }
    }
    //Here we just dump some info for testing purposes
    echo $testNo.': Action taken = '.$actionTaken;
    if($actionTaken=='Block') echo ' - Call terminated.';
    if($actionTaken=='Mod') echo ' - New number = '.$finalNo;
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

View the output demo [on phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p2i-ry8) (click Run/F9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterisk realtime architecture and correct view to match extensions table.

Or you can use mysql query with REGEXP/RLIKE construction.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

You can easy change asterisk regexp to general regexp by using simple rewrites like

```
  '.' -> '.*'
  'X' -> '[0-9]'
```

etc

Comment: Thanks for that response.  Really, I am not acquainted about asterisk realtime (in fact, didn't know that existed), but a quick lookout I made shows that is the correct way to go in this scenario.  For the moment, I will just keep playing with PHP, but I will read and learn more about the realtime architecture in the near future.  Good answer. Thanks.

Comment: You should not go php varaiant if you ever expect productional load on that system.